# DataMapper Dates

Tags: ruby, date, sinatra, datamapper

Forgive me if this is a simple answer.

But how do you get a Date from a DataMapper property. For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'datamapper'

class Test
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :created_at, Date
end

get '/:id' do
    test = Test.get(1)

    test.created_at = ?
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it with the functions from 
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/DateTime.html

For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'datamapper'

class Test
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Serial
    property :created_at, Date
end

get '/:id' do
    test = Test.get(1)

    test.created_at.strftime(fmt='%F %T')
end
```

will return a date formatted YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Or indeed

```
test.created_at.to_time
```

returns a date such as `2011-07-14 00:09:32 +0100`, including the offset.

Or

```
test.created_at.strftime("%c")
```

returns a date defined in the local format, such as `Thu Jul 14 00:09:32 2011`.

Or either of

```
test.created_at.iso8601
test.created_at.to_s
```

returns a date in ISO 8601 format, such as `2011-07-14T00:09:32+01:00`.

Oh, and it isn't necessary to specify `fmt=`; you can do

```
test.created_at.strftime("%F %T")
```

However, if you just want the date, you can do

```
test.created_at.to_date.to_s
```

which returns `"2011-07-14"`.

Bear in mind, also, that you can use `created_on`, if you only want to store a Date, and never a DateTime.